# Fatal error login Wordpress

Tags: php, wp-admin, errors, html, cookies

When I want to login to my wordpress this appears:

Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: setcookie(): "path" option cannot contain ",", ";", " ", "\t", "\r", "\n", "\013", or "\014" in C:\xampp\htdocs\sicarmx\wp-login.php:418 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sicarmx\wp-login.php(418): setcookie('wordpress_test_...', 'WP Cookie check', 0, ' /sicarmx/', '', false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sicarmx\wp-login.php on line 418

I need to know if it has happened to someone and how can I solve it please, I have tried everything at this point.

Comment: What version of XAMPP, PHP and SQL are you running? This looks to be a local install of your site on Windows. If so, how did you set up your site - from a migration or clean install of WP?

Comment: You've already asked this here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/395283/wordpress-log-in-fatal-error-cookies, update your question, don't post duplicate questions